# Different colors or shades for geom_point and geom_smooth on ggplot for multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
data1 <- data.frame(x = 1:15,    # Create example data frame
                   y = c(runif(15, 0, 2),
                         runif(15, 2, 6),
                         runif(15, 3, 4),
                         runif(15, 1, 3)),
                   group = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 15))

ggplot(data1, aes(x,y, color=group))+
  geom_point() +
geom_smooth(se=FALSE)
```

[image]

I have the following plot, and I would like to make the colors of the `geom_smoth` be slightly different than points (I.e. darker shade), I can't figure out how I can do it

Comment: I can't work on it now, but you might look into `ggnewscale` so you can have a different color scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @r2evans and @TarJae!

```
ggplot(data1, aes(x, y, group = group)) +
 geom_point(aes(color=group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey70", "red", "green", "steelblue"))+
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_smooth(aes(color=group),se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("grey20", "darkred", "darkgreen", "blue"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update after clarification:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot(data1, aes(x,y, color=group)) +
  geom_point(alpha=0.5)+
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_smooth(color = "blue", se=FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "purple"))
```

[image]

Comment: no, i want to specify different colors. this methods does not work for me- i have too many points- so the lines are very hard to see,