# How to plot two sets of line with two color palette in r ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The sample dataset is as below:

```
structure(list(Date = c("2011-12-01", "2011-12-01", "2011-12-02", 
"2011-12-02", "2011-12-03", "2011-12-03", "2011-12-04", "2011-12-04", 
"2011-12-05", "2011-12-05", "2011-12-06", "2011-12-06", "2011-12-07", 
"2011-12-07", "2011-12-08", "2011-12-08", "2011-12-09", "2011-12-09", 
"2011-12-10", "2011-12-10", "2011-12-11", "2011-12-11", "2011-12-12", 
"2011-12-12", "2011-12-13", "2011-12-13", "2011-12-14", "2011-12-14", 
"2011-12-15", "2011-12-15", "2011-12-16", "2011-12-16", "2011-12-17", 
"2011-12-17", "2011-12-18", "2011-12-18", "2011-12-19", "2011-12-19", 
"2011-12-20", "2011-12-20", "2011-12-21", "2011-12-21", "2011-12-22", 
"2011-12-22", "2011-12-23", "2011-12-23", "2011-12-24", "2011-12-24", 
"2011-12-25", "2011-12-25", "2011-12-26", "2011-12-26", "2011-12-27", 
"2011-12-27", "2011-12-28", "2011-12-28", "2011-12-29", "2011-12-29", 
"2011-12-30", "2011-12-30", "2011-12-31", "2011-12-31"), value = c(21.8, 
14.9, 17.8, 13.4, 19.4, 11.8, 20.2, 14.4, 20.2, 18.1, 21.8, 17.6, 
24.5, 20.4, 22.9, 15.7, 16.3, 13.4, 15.9, 11, 16.3, 9.6, 18.6, 
11.7, 20.7, 14.1, 21.6, 17.7, 22.2, 17.5, 19, 15.1, 17.8, 14.4, 
18.6, 13.6, 19.2, 14, 18.7, 16.7, 22, 17.2, 20.5, 16.1, 17.7, 
12.6, 15.6, 10.6, 15.9, 10.3, 17.9, 13.9, 18, 15.1, 20.6, 15.1, 
20.7, 16.1, 19.6, 16.5, 19.8, 14.8), temp = c("max", "min", "max", 
"min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", 
"max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", 
"min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", 
"max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", 
"min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", 
"max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", "min", "max", 
"min", "max", "min", "max", "min")), row.names = c(NA, -62L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

which is meteorological data with maximum and minimum temperatures from Dec of 2011.

First, I tried to plot the graph with the code below:

```
data %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = value, color = temp)) +
         geom_line(linewidth = 0.1) + 
         geom_smooth(method = 'loess', span = 0.2) +
         theme_classic()
```

The result:
[image]

In the graph, the lines that represented the original data were overlapped with the smoothing lines. Since the same color palette was used for these two sets of lines, it wasn't easy to read.

So I tried to change the color palette of the smoothing lines:

```
> data %>% ggplot(aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = value, color = temp)) +
           geom_line(linewidth = 0.1) + 
           geom_smooth(aes(color = c('red','blue')),method = 'loess', span = 0.2) +
           theme_classic()
```

But the error popped up:

```
Error in `geom_smooth()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (62)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `color`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have considered using `scale_color_manual`  but am unsure if it will only change the color palette of smoothing lines or both sets of lines.

Please give me some suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Probably working with `ggnewscale::new_scale_color` will solve your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870651/different-colors-or-shades-for-geom-point-and-geom-smooth-on-ggplot-for-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a combination of `ggplot2::scale_color_manual()` and `ggnewscale::new_scale_color()`. This approach gives you control over the colour of every line:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data = data,
              aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = value, colour = temp),
              linewidth = 1,
              method = 'loess',
              span = 0.2,
              show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("cyan4", "hotpink3")) +
  new_scale_color() +
  geom_line(data = data,
            aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = value, colour = temp),
            linewidth = .75) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue")) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: result]